mypy infer type signature from called function
Is there a way to to infer type signature of a caller from a called function?
In the example below, the (overloaded) Test1.f function works as expected. The Test2.get_arg().f also works.
The question is: What is the proper (shortest) way to implement Test2.f in a type safe way or what is the closest workaround? The Test2.f is just a shortcut to Test2.get_arg().f. I would like to avoid repeating type signature of Test2.f if possible.
This is the example:
from typing import *

class Test1:
    @overload
    def f(self, key: Literal['A']) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def f(self, key: Literal['B']) -> str: ...
    def f(self, key: Any) -> Any:
        if key == 'A': return 1
        elif key == 'B': return 'x'
        assert_never(key)

class Test2:
    def __init__(self, arg: Test1):
        self._arg = arg

    def get_arg(self) -> Test1:
        return self._arg

    # How to tell to 'mypy' that 'f' is the same as 'get_arg().f',
    # without repeating the (overload) definition?
    # This works in runtime, but not for 'mypy'
    def f(self, key):
        return self.get_arg().f(key)

test2 = Test2(Test1())

# this works as expected
print(test2.get_arg().f('A') + 1)
#print(test2.get_arg().f('B') + 1) # <- mypy error (str + int)
#print(test2.get_arg().f('C')) # <- mypy error (no overload)

# we would like to have the same type safety with shortcut 'f'
print(test2.f('A') + 1)
#print(test2.f('B') + 1) # <- we want type error here
#print(test2.f('C')) # <- and here

I have tryed to put various type signatures, for example:
def f(self, key: Any) -> Any:
def f(self, key: Union[Literal['A'], Literal['B']]) -> Any:

It fixed some problems, but mypy still does not know what a return type is. I am not sure if this approach is correct.
Edit:
Based on similar questions, I have managed to make it work for a simple case, like this:
from typing import *

T = TypeVar('T')

def same_as(f: T) -> Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], T]:
    def wrap(_g): # ignore wrapped function, use 'f'
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap

@overload
def f(v: Literal[1]) -> int: ...

@overload
def f(v: Literal[2]) -> str: ...

def f(v: Any) -> Any:
    if v == 1: return 1
    elif v == 2: return 'x'
    assert_never(v)

@same_as(f)
def g(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    ...

# types are the same, functions behave the same
reveal_type(f)
reveal_type(g)

However, the problem remains in the original situation with objects. My intention was:
from typing import *

T = TypeVar('T')

def same_as(f: T) -> Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], T]:
    def wrap(_g): # ignore wrapped function, use 'f'
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap

class Test1:
    @overload
    def f(self, key: Literal['A']) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def f(self, key: Literal['B']) -> str: ...
    def f(self, key: Any) -> Any:
        if key == 'A': return 1
        elif key == 'B': return 'x'
        assert_never(key)

class Test2:
    def __init__(self, arg: Test1):
        self._arg = arg

    def get_arg(self) -> Test1:
        return self._arg

    @same_as(Test1.f)
    def f(self, key):
        ...

test2 = Test2(Test1())

reveal_type(test2.get_arg().f)
reveal_type(test2.f)

But the problem is that methods are not exactly the same any more, due to the difference in self argument (Test1 vs. Test2). This is the mypy` error:
test.py:36: error: Invalid self argument "Test2" to attribute function "f" with type "Callable[[Test1, Literal['A']], int]"  [misc]

The error makes sense. I have tryed with several variations of same_as type signature to tweak the first argument, but none works. I would appreciate a suggestion.

Possible duplicates: How to annotate the type of arguments forwarded to another function?, Copy type signature from another function.

Note that Callable[[Any], Any] is too general for both Test1.f and Test2.get_arg. They should be Callable[[LIteral["A", "B"]], str | int]. I would, however, define two separate methods in Test1 with types Callable[[], str] and Callable[[], int], and make the caller use the value of key to decide which method to call. (The same goes for Test2.get_arg itself.)
